# Object of type NoneType using threads

Tags: python, multithreading, thread-safety

I have the following class

```
queue = Queue.Queue()
class SpectraProcessing(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, queue, pbar = None, image_infos = []):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.queue = queue
        self.pbar = pbar
        self.image_infos = image_infos

    def run(self):
        while True:
        spectrum = self.queue.get()
        self.image_infos.append(get_spectrumInfos(spectrum))

        #signal to queue job has been done
        if self.pbar:
            self.pbar.update(self.pbar.currval + 1)
        self.queue.task_done()
```

msrun is an iterator over Spectrum objects created with the class Reader:

```
msrun = pimzml.run.Reader(file_imzML, file_ibd, MSn_Precision = 250e-6)
```

each spectrum object has an attribute list that will(initially it is []) contains the intensities (float values).
My main function contain this:

```
number_spectra = len(msrun)   
print "start creating the image from spectra..."
pbar = ProgressBar( maxval = number_spectra ).start()

#spawn a pool of threads, and pass them a queue instance
image_infos = []
for i in range(number_spectra):
    t = SpectraProcessing(queue, pbar, image_infos)
    t.setDaemon(True)
    t.start()
#populate queue with data
for spectrum in msrun:
    queue.put(spectrum)

#wait on the queue until everything has been processed
queue.join()
```

`get_spectrumInfos(spectrum)` function called by the run method, handles (fill the list with intensities, ...) the list of intensities of each spectrum.
when I execute I get the error that the list of intensities is NoneType (i.e.; empty), some times the execution is doing without any error. Without using Threads there is no error.

Thank a lot.

Comment: This does not answer your question, but it is dubious that all your threads append to the same list. It may work thanks to GIL, but you should use another queue for the results. Also, you are creating as many threads as the number of objects in queue. Create a small number of threads instead. Your actual problem may be in code you didn't post.

Comment: Also, an error about NoneType has nothing to do with an error that a list is empty.  It means that the variable or attribute contains None.